# Plot lines in different layers- ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have three vectors that look similar to these ones, in R and I would like to plot them on the same plot

```
a <- c(3, 6, 16, 17, 11, 21)
b <- c(0.3, 2.3, 9, 9, 5 ,12)
c <- c(3, 7, 9, 7, 6, 10)
```

Does anyone know can I write the following commands using the ggplot2 package?

```
colours <- rainbow(3)
plot(a, col=colours[1], type="l", ylim=c(min(m), max(m)),
     xlab="time[h]", main="bla")
lines(b, col=colours[2])
lines(c, col=colours[3])
legend(x="bottomright", legend=c("a","b", "c"),
       col=c(colours[1],colours[2],colours[3]), pch=19, inset=0.01)
```

I have only managed to plot individual lines or to plot them using faceting- by creating a data frame from the vectors.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, we do.

First, place your data in a data frame and use `melt` to transform it to a 'long' format:

```
dat <- data.frame(a=a,b=b,c=c)
dat <- melt(dat)
```

next we add an explicit 'x' variable to our data frame:

```
dat$x <- rep(1:6,times=3)
```

Finally, we can plot the graph using the following code:

```
ggplot(dat,aes(x=x,y=value)) + 
    geom_line(aes(colour=variable)) + 
    scale_colour_manual(values=colours) + 
    labs(x="time[h]",y="a",colour="") + 
    opts(title="bla")
```

Comment: It looks just perfect! melting data and grouping are the keys :-) + plus a lot of ggplot experience! Cheers!

Comment: I changed my answer slightly, since group= isn't strictly necessary here, the colour aesthetic gets the job done in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
a<-c(3,6,16,17,11,21) 
b<-c(0.3, 2.3, 9, 9, 5 ,12) 
c<-c(3, 7,9, 7, 6 ,10)
x <- 1:6

df <- data.frame(a,b,c,x)
require(reshape)
dfm <- melt(df, id = "x")

require(ggplot2)
ggplot(dfm, aes(x = x, y = value, col = variable)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  theme_bw() +
  opts(panel.grid.major = theme_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = theme_blank(),
    legend.position = c(.9, .2),
    title = "bla") +
  ylab("a") +
  xlab("time [h]") +
  scale_color_discrete("")
```

Comment: @EDi- that works as well, I actually needed the "standard" ggplot grid but now I can play around with the options.

Comment: @EDi-I imagined and now I know how to do it if I need that to be changed. Thanks.